# tool to trace application without code changes?

Tags: .net, reverse-engineering, trace

I've inherited a rather large WPF application, and I need to generate application traces for a significant portion of it.  Because of the complexity of the project, I'd like to do this without making any changes to the code base, if possible.  I mostly need to know the stack deltas, ie when a function call or return takes place.  Is there a tool or methodology that will get me this trace with (preferably) no code changes?  Is this even possible to do without writing a tool to add Trace calls to the code?

If it were limited to specific function calls, i think i could live with that.  I have a tool that can do that for win32 api calls, via import table rewriting to redirect the dll function call to a custom stub that logs the call stack at that point.  If there is no such tool that works 'out of the box' on .NET, does anyone know of a FAQ or something that explains how .NET DLL linkage works (export table, thunks, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an answer that would be useful, it really is important to know *why* you need an application trace.

I can think, one of:

1. For analysis purposes (understanding things at an architectural level).  In this case, what would be appropriate is a static code analysis tool such as [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/);
2. For logging purposes (once again, why specifically would you need to know method entrance and exits?).  In this case, since you don't want to have to change the source, an aspect orientation framework that injects aspects just before execution is probably what you're looking for, e.g., [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).
3. For performance analysis purposes.  In this case, use the tool that comes with Visual Studio, or a commercial tool such as [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index2.htm).

Other AOP solutions exist that would be suited to intercepting method calls (e.g., [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)) but these require changes to the source (albeit relatively small ones) which you've already said that you're not interested in.

Comment: Due to the large size of the application, I'm looking for an architectural analysis, as you say.  I'll look into NDepend, thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You could inject method calls (to `Trace` or whatever suits your fancy) using [PostSharp Core](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/##stSharp.HxS/UserGuide/CoreLibrary/Overview.html), though it's not an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) provides automatic tracing of .NET applications without any changes to the code base.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio IDE allows the definition of "breakpoints" that output a string to all attached trace listeners. This string can be composed from any number of in-scope variables. By default this kind of breakpoint does not pause execution. You can use the config file to attach other trace listeners if you want a trace file.

These breakpoint definitions are saved as part of your solution's IDE state, so you won't have to set them up every time.