# How to find all methods currently subscribed to an event in WPF / C# during debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am quite new to WPF and rather new to C# and now have inherited a C#/WPF App with over 60k lines of code (no MVVM was used, the design pattern is rather improvised). Now, I have to change a rather small thing in the UI, but this control is quite crucial and therefore heavily woven into the whole solution. I know the "Live Visual Tree" Function in Visual Studio and also I know the Live Property Explorer. However, I would like to have something like a "Live EVENT Explorer" to see what methods are registered to an event of this control. I would like to have something like:

a) A possibility to see, what methods are currently subscribed to a certain event (for example the SelectionChanged event of a ListView). With "currently" I mean, that the subscribed methods are changing quite a lot depending on what radio buttons and check boxes are selected, etc. So I would like to make all the selections I need and then inspect the control and see what methods are subscribed to one of its events.

b) A possibility to stop right in the first method that is being triggered by this event if I for example change the selection in my control. So that I can step through all the following code?

Does anyone of you have an idea if either one of this is possible with a built-in function in Visual Studio and also how to do it? Or is there maybe another tool out there how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Good question. This I should have mentioned. No MVVM was used. The design pattern is rather "improvised". Also the colleague who wrote most of it is not in the company anymore.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191433/tool-to-trace-application-without-code-changes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978364/debugging-all-events-in-visual-studio-2010-without-setting-break-points.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? Does the answers below solve your problem??

Comment: After some testing, the answer of Mitch fits my question best, but also the answer of Nekeniehl is a good one (i.e. combined with #IF Debug preprocessor instruction), depending on the situation. Also his comment about the Snoop Tool helped me a lot (in general). With all the answers and comments, I figured out a way of working which is fine for me for the moment. But originally I hoped that there was maybe a kind of tool where I can just inspect a WPF control and see all methods subscribed to an event, similar to Live Property viewer. But such a tools seems not to exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, Find All References should have it covered, but this fails when the event is not unique enough (imagine Button.Click).

You can access this in a debugger by browsing to the event object and examining the `_invocationList` field.  If this field is not populated, look at `_methodPtr` field.  If both fields are null, then no one is subscribed.

`_target` is the object containing the subscribed method.  If it is null, a static method is subscribed (which makes identification [much more tricky](http://julmar.com/blog/debugging/sos-finding-the-method-bound-to-an-eventhandler-with-windbg/)).  Otherwise, you can [dump the method table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682594/138200) of the target object to find the subscribed method.

In Visual studio, the debug tooltips make this easy.  For a unicast delegate, hovering over the event shows the declaring type and method name (and arity if needed):

[image: screencap showing debugger tooltip]

for multicast, the `_invocationList` takes over:

[image: screencap showing debugger tooltip]