Is it possible to know which code (which methods in which classes) have run during a time period?
I have a use case that when I'm new to a complex project, debugging can be tough.
Specially if there are a lot of lambda or delegates or async code involved.
I was curious, is it possible to know which pieces of code have been run during a time period, by specifying a start and end point in time?
This can help narrow down the locations you need to check to find what you're looking for, and continue debugging from there.
I though of a static tool that changes all files and adds a log to start of each method with that method and class name, and then another script to remove the duplicates in output.
Also, some profilers can be used, but their output is not clean for this use case and can involve a lot of manual work too.
So I was curious does any tool exist to do this in a clean way?
Edit: I don't have an Enterprise Subscription for VS, but I'm curious if IntelliTrace could do something like that.

You can start the Visual Studio profiler suspended and then turn data collection on as the part you're interested in starts (assuming you can somehow tell). I have VS Ent - I don't know if this feature is specific to that version.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191433/tool-to-trace-application-without-code-changes
