Trace which methods are called during program execution?
I want to trace which methods are called during the execution of my c# program. How is that possible using Rider or Visual Studio?
Use case:
In one of my projects, I am getting an error about a disposed object (inside a library). I don't understand where this is coming from, so my idea is to trace all methods that get executed and then search for "Dispose" in the list of executed methods.

The thing that immediately springs to mind is Jetbrains DotTrace (paid for, 30 day trial available). But I'd probably attack this particular problem from the other end - find which object has been disposed then follow its lifecycle through the code.

Do you get a stack trace when this error occurs (I'm guess your "error about a disposed object (inside a library)" is an exception). If so, you know which methods were called before the error occurred. If they were all called synchronously, then you should be off to the races. If you have asynchronicity in there it gets more complicated. Don't just look for Dispose, look for using as well

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191433/tool-to-trace-application-without-code-changes

As Iakobski says, you can try JetBrains dotTrace.After dowload  JetBrains dotTrace, choose your application to profile and choose "Tracing" as your profiling Type.

After Starting profiling, you click "get snapshot" and you will get a Call Tree which records all your all methods that get executed.



In Visual Studio,

go to Debug|Windows|Exception Settings, make sure that it will break on "CLR Exceptions" and "Managed Debugging Assistants"
start your application under Visual Studio Debugger
when exception in Dispose occurs, Visual Studio Debugger will stop
go to Debug|Windows|Call Stack, you will see who was calling whom. You can also double-click on the line in the Call Stack window. This will bring you to that line in your code, and you will be able to see all variables visible in that particular stack frame.

